# Retrieving required set-off json objects using through "Jq" method

Tags: json, shell, unix, split, jq

I have below mentioned Json file. I wanted to do the below checks.

1. Get 1st 5 objects from the whole list and save them in a separate file (i.e FirstTopObject.json)
2. Get another set-off 5 objects and store them into another file (i.e SecondTopObject.json)
3. Get the last 5 objects and store them into another file (i.e ThirdTopObject.json)

Basically, wanted to split the Objects based on the Numbers and save them into a separate file.

Is there any solution is available to achieve through the **“jq”** function/method?

Input File:

```
{
  "storeId": "0001"
}
{
  "storeId": "0002"
}
{
  "storeId": "0003"
}
{
  "storeId": "0004"
}
{
  "storeId": "0005"
}
{
  "storeId": "0006"
}
{
  "storeId": "0007"
}
{
  "storeId": "0008"
}
{
  "storeId": "0009"
}
{
  "storeId": "00010"
}
{
  "storeId": "00011"
}
{
  "storeId": "00012"
}
{
  "storeId": "00013"
}
{
  "storeId": "00014"
}
{
  "storeId": "00015"
}
enter code here
enter code here
```

Expecting output:
FirstTopObject.json should have the below set.

```
{
  "storeId": "0001"
}
{
  "storeId": "0002"
}
{
  "storeId": "0003"
}
{
  "storeId": "0004"
}
{
  "storeId": "0005"
}
```

SecondTopObject.json - shold contain below setoff objects.

```
{
  "storeId": "0006"
}
{
  "storeId": "0007"
}
{
  "storeId": "0008"
}
{
  "storeId": "0009"
}
{
  "storeId": "00010"
}
```

Like wise for other set.

It Would be more helpful if some help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify the requirements.  E.g., if there are 1,000,000 objects in the input file, do you still want just three files with 5 objects in each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use JQ to process the input file - reformat it using `-c` (compact) and then use standard unix tools to split the files, i.e.

```
cat input | jq --slurp -c .[] | head -5 | jq . > FirstTopObject.json
cat input | jq --slurp -c .[] | sed '6,10!d' | jq . > SecondTopObject.json
cat input | jq --slurp -c .[] | tail -5 | jq . > ThirdTopObject.json
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Its working as expected.Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to slurp the input file!  Even if the output must be pretty-printed, there is no need for more than four invocations of jq altogether.

### Handling a small input file

If the input is not so big, you can simply run

```
  jq -c . input
```

directing the output to a temporary file, and then split that file into three using whichever standard command-line tools you find most convenient (a single invocation of awk might be worth considering ...).

#### Handling a very large input file

If the input file is very large, then it would make sense to use jq just to copy the (15) items of interest into a temporary file, and then process that file:

**Step 1**
Invoke the following program with `jq -cn`:

```
def echo($n1; $n2; $last):
   foreach (inputs,null) as $in ({ix:-1, first:[], second:[], last:[]};
      if $in then
        .ix += 1
        | if .ix < $n1
          then .first += [$in]
          elif .ix < $n1+n2 then .second += [$in]
          else .last += [$in]
          | .last = (.last[ - $last: ])
          end
       else . end;
      if $in == null then del(.ix) else empty end
      )
      | .[];

echo(5;5;5)
```

(This program is somewhat complex because it makes no assumptions about the relative sizes of the three blocks.)

**Step 2**
Assuming the output from Step 1 is in input.tmp, then run:

```
 sed -n 1p input.tmp | jq .[] > FirstTopObject.json
 sed -n 2p input.tmp | jq .[] > SecondTopObject.json
 sed -n 3p input.tmp | jq .[] > ThirdTopObject.json
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of the jq functions `to_entries` and `group_by` for this, along with a little bash.

This snippet will create 25 strings (`"line 0"`, `"line 1"`, etc.), group them by 5s, and write them into files `0.json`, `1.json`, etc. Everything before `to_entries` can be replaced with any list. In your case, you can use the slurp flag `-s` to get all your JSON objects in your input file into a list.

```
FILE_NUM=0
jq -nc '
  # create input
  ["line " + (range(25) | tostring)] | 

  # process input
  to_entries | group_by(.key / 5 | floor)[] | map(.value)
' | while read LINE; do echo "$LINE" > "/tmp/$((FILE_NUM++)).json"; done
```